# Take python exit status and use it in bash command

Tags: python, bash, return-code

I have a Python script that returns a status when it finishes (but not through an output).

```
sys.exit(status)
```

And I have to run a bash command that uses that status, the execution is something like:

```
command --host=xxx --service="xxx" --message="`myscript.py`" -s "ip" -u "user" -p "pass" " --returncode=0
```

Is there any way to take the return code directly from the "sys.exit(status)"?

I tried changing `--returncode=0` to `--returncode=$?` but it does not work.

Comment: There is some kind of error in the code snippet that you posted, there is only one `

Comment: You want a bash command to specify the python script to be run and to know a priori the return value the script will yield? That doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson The status is a variable from that script (used by Nagios), so there is no way to take it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the script exits, bash has the exit code in variable `$?`. But invoking another command would change that exit code. So you should save it to a variable right after the script returns.

You could write something like:

```
python3 script.py
status=$?
command --returncode=$status
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use [templating](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/) or hardcode the status in there if you want to be sure that it returns the status you want, but that basically removes the use case of having an exit code/status. ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68378440/take-python-exit-status-and-use-it-in-bash-command/68378643#comment120846542_68378440))

Other than that, the exit code is available by POSIX shell in `$?` variable, but you can also return an output you want and check for that e.g. return common output in STDOUT and return errors, or for your case a custom "exit code" string in STDERR [like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474195/296803).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

sys_exit_code.py

```
import sys
status = 12
sys.exit(status)
```

sys_exit_code.sh

```
python sys_exit_code.py
RC=$?
echo "Exit code $RC"
```

run you bash script

```
sh sys_exit_code.sh
```